# How can I avoid write operations while deleting the all data from Google App Engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine development. We have developed application with android and Google App Engine.We tried to delete all data but write operations became 100% and we can not simply delete further records. How can we manage to delete the data without exceeding 100%.

Can someone please explain us so we can follow the steps.

Thanks,

Prashant

Comment: Turn on the billing and pay for it, remove 500k every day (but firstly you should vacuum all indexes) or just forget about it -- storage is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot delete records without accounting it for in the quota.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls

> Entity Delete (per entity) -->    2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value

So if you are in free-quota, you cannot delete or write any further, without enable billing.

**Work around**

Google allows 25 free app-engine projects to each user id. Create a new project and upload the old project code to new project id. If your daily traffic is within the free quota, you can use it as long as you want.